# how to wrap text in angularjs and save the position

Tags: angularjs

I would like to wrap text with span tag and save the position.
I know how to do it with JS but i dont know how to do it with angularjs

Here is what i have done:

http://jsfiddle.net/ymeaL06j/1/

This function gives me the position of the text in the DIV

```
function getSelectionPosition() {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
  preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById("code"));
  preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
  var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

  return {
    start: start,
    end: start + range.toString().length
  }
};
```

I take the start and end positions and insert them as an attribute in the span tag

After this i would like to save all the marked positions and load it later, i have a function that select text and then i can wrap it (i hope that there is a better solution)

```
function setSelection(savedSel) {
  var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(document.getElementById("code"), 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

  while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
      if (node.nodeType == 3) {
          var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
          if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
              range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
              foundStart = true;
          }
          if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
              range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
              stop = true;
          }
          charIndex = nextCharIndex;
      } else {
          var i = node.childNodes.length;
          while (i--) {
              nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
          }
      }
  }

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

Comment: AngularJS is a JS framework. It's not a language. If you can do it in JS, you can do it in AngularJS.

Comment: yes but i doesn't understand how to do that the span tag will be with angularjs binding ({{ something }})

Comment: It might help if you change the title of your question. Really you are asking if one can use plain old javascript in angularjs. Your current title will get down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same code that you illustrated above and put it inside of your angularjs controller.

**Refer to [my plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/yBAGOMOyPu2K4wGIvLfp?p=preview); it is a simple angularjs version of your jsfiddle code.**

For example, suppose that a snippet of the `index.html` looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="code">This is <b>some text</b> bla bla bla</div>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Mark!" ng-click="markText()" />
  <input type="button" value="Remove marks!" ng-click="removeMarks()" />
</body>
```

Then the example angularjs controller, `MainCtrl`, could look like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var getSelectionPosition = function () { 
     var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
     var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
     preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById("code"));
     preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
     var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

     return {
        start: start,
        end: start + range.toString().length
     }
  }

  $scope.markText = function() {
    var currPosition = getSelectionPosition();
    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "Mark";
    span.setAttribute("PosStart", currPosition.start);
    span.setAttribute("PosEnd", currPosition.end);
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
  };

 $scope.removeMarks = function() {
    $(".Mark").each(function () {
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
    });
 };

});
```

Notice that the `MainCtrl` is the angularjs controller for the body. The `ng-click` on the buttons reference the `markText` and `removeMarks` functions in the controller's scope. The logic in the functions are exactly the same as you referenced in your question (and jsfiddle).

None of your JS code changed other than moving the functions inside of the controller. Again, check out the plunker above to see the actual code working.

Comment: in this case, arent we manipulating the DOM in the controller ?